# How to set the colour of a text in a textarea using html input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, textarea

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform">
  Select Color : <input type="color" onClick="Color()">
</form>

<textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14" placeholder="Enter Text Here ..."></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Color() {
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.color = ''; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

In this same way, how would I set a specific font(family-font) to a particular word in the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input type color it makes sense to use `onchange` event. It will work as you need:

```
<input type="color" onchange="Color(this)">
```

JS

```
function Color(obj) {
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.color = obj.value;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xRBLT/

Answer (score 1):

Use `onkeyup` instead of `onclick`.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform">
    Select Color : <input type="color" onkeydown="Color(this.value)">
</form>
<textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14" placeholder="Enter Text Here ..."></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
function Color(s){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.color = s; 
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8cfK/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to apply the selected color for text.

```
<input type="color" onClick="Color(this)">

function Color(cthis){
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.color = cthis.value 
}
```

To apply the font-famly into element `textarea` you could do something like this.

```
document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.fontFamily="Arial";
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8QfUs/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<input type="color" id="color"/>
```

With some jQuery:

```
$("#color").change(function(){
var clr = $(this).val();
$("#myTextArea").css("color",clr);
});
```

No OnClick or something let jQuery do the things.

http://jsfiddle.net/j2Y6s/

Comment: No jQuery tag on question

Comment: it looks like he is not really familiar with Javascript so jQuery would be a good option because it will take away some things like OnClick or handling with parameter

Comment: He isnt familiar with javascript so let him learn that first.this is jumping 2 steps ahead

Comment: I knw.I myself would have answered a jQuery answer if the question contained the tag.But it is hard for a beginner to understand jQuery(even simple) if he doesnt know the basic javascript